# MySQL returned an empty result - Trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm creating a trigger in MySQL but I have a problem, MySQL return "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)";

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_transaction BEFORE 
INSERT ON transaction 
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE montantTotalTransaction FLOAT;
        DECLARE montantObjet FLOAT;
        DECLARE montantTotalNewTransaction FLOAT;
        DECLARE idPotObjet INTEGER;
        DECLARE idPotAmi INTEGER;

        SET @montantTotalTransaction := (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(montant),2),0) FROM objet o, transaction t WHERE o.id = NEW.id_objet and t.id_objet = o.id);
        SET @prixObjet := (SELECT prix FROM objet WHERE id = NEW.id_objet);
        SET @montantTotalNewTransaction := @montantTotalTransaction + NEW.montant;
        SET @idPotObjet := (SELECT id_pot FROM objet WHERE id = NEW.id_objet);
        SET @idPotAmi := (SELECT id_pot FROM ami WHERE nom = NEW.id_ami);

        IF NEW.montant < 0 THEN
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Le montant de la transaction ne peut être négatif';
        END IF;

        IF @montantTotalNewTransaction >  @prixObjet THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'La somme de toutes les transactions sur cet objet est plus grande que le prix de l\'objet';
        END IF;

        IF @idPotObjet <> @idPotAmi THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45004' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'L\'ami et l\'objet n\'appartiennent pas au même pot';
        END IF;
    END;
```

an idea ?

Thank in advance !!

Comment: How is this related to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It's possible. I think that MySQL define a size limit for queries.